# script tag doesn't follow tree structure jquery parseHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

I'm parsing some HTML through jquery's parseHTML() function:

```
<code>
<b>test</b><script>lol</script> 
</code>
```

Problem is, that when it comes to `<script>` tags, they seem to have a mind of their own.

```
dom = $.parseHTML(txt,document,true);
```

`dom` now looks like this `[code, script]` with the script tag **outside** of the code tag. How can I make sure it stays within it, as the `<b>` does?

Thanks

Comment: Why does it matter where it's physically located? Just wondering, since I have no idea what this is actually being used for

Comment: The script tag needs to stay within the code tag as it's coming through as a code snippet, rather than an actual piece of script.

Comment: I am an idiot and can't believe I didn't realize that, haha sorry

Comment: So what do you expect to happen? The `<b>` should apply the bold style, but should the `<script>` just be visible and show its code? `<script>` elements aren't visible, and are meant to execute code. For example, if you weren't parsing it, and just had it on your HTML page, you still wouldn't see `<script>` in the code block. If you want the `<script>` to be visible, change the `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: I know, but even doing this has the same affect :\ unless I'm just going crazy...

Comment: You might be going crazy :) http://jsfiddle.net/4EZ9C/ Maybe I'm the crazy one...

Comment: Aha! Not sure where I went wrong before but that's great - thanks :)